# Как определить движок браузера?

Tags: webbrowser

Как определить движок браузера? Желательно определить не по таблице в wiki, а программным путем или где-то в самом браузере.

Comment: Что Вы имеете ввиду говоря о "движке браузера"? Содержимое заголовка User_Agent: из текущего запроса? Определить нужно на стороне сервера или на стороне клиента?

Comment: @Streletz Я просматриваю страницу через браузер и нужно определить движок  вот - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%BA   А могу ли я узнать, причем движок на сервер к браузеру?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Если нужно определять на клиенте:

Есть библиотека на javascript. Называется [Layout Engine](http://mattstow.com/layout-engine.html).

- Распознает следующие движки: `edge`, `ie`, `khtml`, `mozilla`, `opera` и `webkit`
- Определяет версии браузеров: `ie-` `11`, `10`, `9`, `8`, `7` и `opera-` `mini`
- Отличает следующие браузеры на WebKit: `android`, `chrome` (*в том числе Opera Blink и Android 5+ WebView*), `safari`, `safari-ios`, а еще `wiiu`.

Вот [демка](http://mattstow.com/experiment/layout-engine/demo.html) с этой библиотекой и ее [исходники](https://github.com/stowball/Layout-Engine).

Пример использования в CSS:

```
.vendor-ie-10 {
    line-height: 20px;
}

.browser-safari-ios .text-input {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

При необходимости версию браузера, да и сам браузер можно определять внутри вашего скрипта на JavaScript, используя следующие методы: `layoutEngine.vendor`, `layoutEngine.version` и `layoutEngine.browser`.

Пример использования в JavaScript:

```
if (layoutEngine.vendor === 'ie' && layoutEngine.version === 10) {
    // Некие действия
}
```

#### Если нужно определять на сервере (например, на PHP):

Есть пакет [WhichBrowser/Parser](https://github.com/WhichBrowser/Parser) для [Composer](https://getcomposer.org). От разработчика [html5test.com](http://html5test.com).

Пример использования:

```
$result = new WhichBrowser\Parser($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

$result->browser->name;
// Chrome

$result->browser->name . ' ' . $result->browser->version.toString();
// Chrome 27

$result->browser->version->value;
// 27.0.1453.110

$result->engine->name;
// Blink
```